# Wrapper cookbook and cookbook_file resource gives FileNotFound error

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

If my base cookbook is something like this:

```
SSLCERT = node[:site][:SSLCert]
cookbook_file SSLCert do
    path "c:/tmp/#{SSLCert}"
    action :create_if_missing
end
```

And my wrapper has

```
override[:site][:SSLCert] = "cert.pfx"
```

I would like to specify the `cert.pfx` file in the wrapper cookbook's `file/default/cert.pfx`

However when I run the wrapper, I get

> FileNotFound: cookbook_file[cert.pfx] does not contain a file at any of these locations....

How do I specify the cookbook file is in the wrapper and not in the base cookbook?

Comment: `#tell the base cookbook where the cert is located
r = resources("cookbook_file[#{node[:site][:SSLCert]}]")
r.cookbook('wrapper_cook_book')`   Found the answer: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045855/chef-rewind-cookbook-file-definition-from-a-wrapper-cookbook-recipe

Comment: Can you update your question to have the exact chef error message

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to change your wrapers cookbook to have files plural with an s instead of file.

```
e.g. files/default/cert.pfx
```

Comment: No, the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045855/chef-rewind-cookbook-file-definition-from-a-wrapper-cookbook-recipe is correct, you just need to let the cookbook_file resource know that the file is located in wrapper even though the resource is defined in the base.  Got it working using the answer from the link.

Comment: Ok glad you got the answer